# Show that the symplectic group $\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is a closed sub group of $\mathrm{Gl}(2n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, lie-groups

I have to show that the symplectic group

$$\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C}):=\{A\in M(2n,\mathbb{C})\mid AJA^{T}=J\},$$

where $J$ denotes the symplectic matrix, is a closed matrix Lie group, e.g. its a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{Gl}(2n,\mathbb{C})$. I have already shown that its a subgroup of $\mathrm{Gl}(2n,\mathbb{C})$.

In order to show thats its closed, I was considering the determinant:

$$\mathrm{det}:\mathrm{Gl}(2n,\mathbb{C})\to\mathbb{C},$$
which is obviously continuous (bec. polynomial). If one looks than at the restriction

$$\mathrm{det}\vert_{\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})}:\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})\to\mathbb{C}$$
which is also a conitnuous map, we have that
$$\mathrm{det}\vert_{\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})}^{-1}(\{-1,1\})=\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$$
and since $\{-1,1\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, we know by continuity that $\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is closed.....

Is this right and/or enough to show closedness?

Comment: The step 

$$\mathrm{det}\vert_{\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})}^{-1}(\{-1,1\})=\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$$
is a little bit flawed. The set $\{-1,+1 \}$ is indeed closed, but by considering this inversion, you show that $\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$ is closed in $\mathrm{Sp}(2n,\mathbb{C})$, but not necessarily in  $\mathrm{Gl}(2n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Oh thats true.....And what if I define the map $T:Gl(2n,\mathbb{C})\to Gl(2n,\mathbb{C})$ such that $T(A):=AJA^{T}-J$. This map is also continuous and we have that $T^{-1}(\{0\})=Sp(2n,\mathbb{C})$....

Comment: @Udalricus.S. That works. You should give an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Udalricus.S.That is indeed a nice solution. All that remains to show is the continuity of the map you suggested.